# Resume session after UIAlert is dismissed

Tags: ios, swift

my Xcode is pretty lousy so don't judge me. I'm trying to pause the captureSession when a user scans an invalid qr code which will trigger an alert message. After the user dismiss the message the captureSession will resume. Really appreciate any help given.

```
        if metadataObj.stringValue == "Booth1"
        {
            captureSession?.stopRunning()
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Vote1", sender: self)
        }
        else {
            captureSession?.stopRunning()
            createAlert(title: "Please enter a valid verfication code", message: "")
            if UIAlertAction.isDismissed {
                captureSession?.startRunning()
            }
        }




//Creating alert
func createAlert (title: String, message: String)
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something when a user selects an option from an `UIAlertController` you do this in the handler for the action.

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { action in 

      self.captureSession?.startRunning()
})
```

This should do what you need, if you are having a more specific issue please update your question.

Comment: Ermm not exactly, I'm using a QR code scanner controller, i want it to be like when he scans an incorrect qr code, the QR scanner will pause/freeze to display an alert message. Only when the user dismiss the alert message then the QR scanner will resume.

Comment: In the above code `self.captureSession?.startRunning()` is the handler for the dismiss button, the code runs when the user taps dismiss. If this is not what you need then I am not understanding your requirements